# Create VPN server on Windows 2022 server programatically

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, windows-server-2022

I'm migrating VPN server from Windows Server 2016 to Windows Server 2022.
This time I want to create it programmatically/automatically (IaC way)?
On Windows Server 2016 is the build-in Windows VPN used.

Details: Users can connect to a server A running Windows Server 2016. What to do so they can connect to new/fresh Virtual Private Server B running Windows Server 2022? Ideally with the same login and password.

The server B has fixed internet IP address.

I prefer to create the new VPN by C# or PowerShell.

To the fresh Windows Server 2022 the RRAS feature can be added by PowerShell script (are all needed for VPN server only?):

```perl
Install-WindowsFeature RemoteAccess
Install-WindowsFeature DirectAccess-VPN -IncludeManagementTool
Install-WindowsFeature Routing -IncludeManagementTools
```

Then probably it's needed to create users. Probably like this:

```perl
net user
```

I can also find how to create VPN connection on the client via

```perl
Add-VpnConnection
```

But I assume that's not all. What to do on the server so the users can connect to it via VPN?

Note: Only Windows (10/11) clients are connecting to the server.